# Set attribute in has_many relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Group` and a `User` which are related through a has_many :through relation. My :through table is called `Groupuser`. This table has a group_id, user_id and a status. On creation of my Group i'd let to set the status of the current_user being added to 1(where default is 0).

Setting the current_user in my group is no problem at all and works perfectly fine; Its status I can't figure out though. This is what I have now:

```
  def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        @group.users << current_user
        @group.groupusers.status << 1
        format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'done' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @group }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Above code throws the error: `undefined method`status' for #`

My schema for Groupuser looks like this: (I've tried without ID aswell, to no avail)

```
  create_table "groupusers", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "status",   default: 0
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@group.groupusers` is an array, activerecord relation. You can't set an attribute like that, you need to set it one by one or before you append it to the group.

```
@group.groupusers.each do |gu|
  gu.status = 1
  gu.save
end
```

or

```
groupuser = GroupUser.new user_id: current_user.id, status: 1
@group.groupusers << groupuser
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
@group.groupusers.status = 1

@group.save!

Comment: Will that only count for the user I'm about to add, though?

Comment: Got this error by the way: `undefined method `status' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Glad that @MurifoX has been able to provide a working solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort nonetheless!